# How to auto login after registration in shopify dawn theme?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a website on shopify.
How to auto login after registration in shopify dawn theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, new customers are auto login to the account page after they register a new account. Kindly follow the below steps to auto-login the customer to a specific page when they register a new account. edit your theme layout/theme.liquid file and add this script before the end of the body tag. and change "REDIRECT_PATH".

```
 <script> 
       (function() { 
 var REDIRECT_PATH = '/account'; // change page url you want redirect after login
       
         var selector = '#create_customer, form[action$="/account"][method="post"]', 
             $form = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0]; 
       
         if ($form) { 
           $redirect = document.createElement('input'); 
           $redirect.setAttribute('name', 'return_to'); 
           $redirect.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
           $redirect.value = REDIRECT_PATH; 
           $form.appendChild($redirect); 
         } 
       })(); 
          </script>
```

Comment: I came across your solution because I have a similar problem. When using your code, I noticed that Shopify fails to check whether the email and password are valid and therefore redirects, but in reality the customer was not registered.
How is this resolved?